# Dates in Oracle Apex Chart's X-Axis not in order

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

I am writing a very simple query in Oracle Apex to draw a chart consisting of dates and the values for those dates. Below is my code:

```
SELECT NULL as Link,  to_char(mydate_column,'DD Mon yyyy') AS "Date", COUNT (*) AS "Values against date"
FROM mytablename
GROUP BY to_char(mydate_column,'DD Mon yyyy')
ORDER BY to_char(mydate_column,'DD Mon yyyy')
```

The chart is generated successfully but the dates from the date columns appear not in order (As shown in the screenshot. Any help on how can i display these dates in chart in ascending order?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are in order as you sorted them. You sorted as "to_char...". Which means you sorted them as a string is where '01 D...' does correctly sort as before '01 J...'. To sort them is date order then just:

```
ORDER BY mydate_column
```

Comment: So dumb I am, not considering that dates are being converted into text. Grouped and sorted by date only and it got fixed. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Not dumb, just falling into a bad habit of copy-paste from select to order by.  Works most of the time. We have all stumbled when it does not. One technique that has server me well: when you do not understand something fall back and "Question your basic assumptions" (those that are on autopilot). It often finds these oops errors. Glad it helped.